# Why are these for loop not working?

Tags: javascript

I have 5 nested for loops:

```
let tags = Tags.find().fetch();
let cases = {};

for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) { 

    cases.problem = {};
    cases.problem.one = {};
    cases.problem.one.name      = tags[i].name;
    cases.problem.one.value     = 50;

    cases.solution = {};

    cases.solution.one      = tags[i].types.slice(0,5);

    for (j = i + 1; j < (tags.length - 1); j++) { 

        cases.problem.two = {};
        cases.problem.two.name      = tags[j].name;
        cases.problem.two.value     = 30;

        cases.solution.two      = tags[j].types.slice(0,3);

        for (k = j + 1; k < (tags.length - 2); k++) {   


            cases.problem.three = {};
            cases.problem.three.name    = tags[k].name;
            cases.problem.three.value   = 20;

            cases.solution.three    = tags[k].types.slice(0,2);

            for (l = k + 1; l < (tags.length - 3); l++) {   

                cases.problem.four = {};
                cases.problem.four.name     = tags[l].name;
                cases.problem.four.value    = 0;

                cases.solution.four     = [""];

                for (n = l + 1; n <= (tags.length - 4); n++) { 

                    cases.problem.five = {}
                    cases.problem.five.name     = tags[n].name;
                    cases.problem.five.value    = 0;

                    cases.solution.five     = [""];

                    console.log(cases)

                    // Cases.insert(cases)

                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

They work fine till the 3er one, I dont know what is wrong.

**NOTE:** Tags.length is always 5.

**NOTE2:** Im trying to make every possible combination of the object stored in the tags array

**NOTE3:** Tags are Object with this form:
    tags: {
     name: String
     types: [Array]
    }

I'll always have 5 tags, so in the code above Tags.find().fetch() will always return 5 objects. Ok what I want/need is this:

```
tags[0] tags[1] tags[2] tags[3] tags[4]
tags[0] tags[1] tags[2] tags[4] tags[3]
....
```

Something like that

Comment: Can you give some sample input/output?

Comment: This seems ripe for a simple recursive implementation.

Comment: *I have 5 nested for loops:* - this is your real problem.

Comment: no output they never finish

Comment: SInce you're just setting properties on the cases.problem object and not changing the tags array in any way, I'm pretty sure this can be done in one loop.

Comment: can you help me pls @Shilly I need to get every combination of the elements stored in tags

Comment: I'm assuming you Don't want to overwrite the cases.problem.number every time? Can you explain a bit more what you mean with 'every combination'? Let's assume you have a tags array like [{'name':'tag1','types':['type1','type2','type3']},{'name':'tag2','types':['type1','type2','type3']},{'name':'tag3','types':['type1','type2','type3']},{'name':'tag4','types':['type1','type2','type3']},{'name':'tag5','types':['type1','type2','type3']}]. What is your desired output?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 2):

The 4th & 5th nested loop will never execute because their conditions are unfulfillable. Take the first iteration where `i = 0`:

Level-1 loop -> `for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)`
Level-2 loop -> `for(j = 1; j < 4; j++)`
Level-3 loop -> `for(k = 2; k < 3; k++)`
Level-4 loop -> `for(l = 3; l < 2; l++)`
Level-5 loop -> `for(n = 4; n <= 1; n++)`

As you can see, from the very first iteration the last two loops will not run.

Comment: It doesnt work, same as before just work till the 3er one

Comment: He is not bringing a solution, he is pointings what's wrong with your program.

Comment: i understand, didnt got it. Thanks